# Historic Stock Prices in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This code is able to get the history of stock prices and the dates are set as the index of the DataFrame.

How can I pass the dates (index) to a column and add the ticker out of iteration to another column?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["GOOG","AMZN"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        tkr = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        hist = tkr.history(period="1y")
        df2 = df2.append(hist)
        print(df2)
```

Result:

```
               Open     High      Low  ...   Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                   ...                                  
2019-06-06  1044.99  1047.49  1033.70  ...  1703200          0             0
2019-06-07  1050.63  1070.92  1048.40  ...  1802400          0             0
2019-06-10  1072.98  1092.66  1072.32  ...  1464200          0             0
```

Objective:

```
Ticker     Date     Open     High      Low  ...   Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits

GOOG 2019-06-06  1044.99  1047.49  1033.70  ...  1703200          0             0
GOOG 2019-06-07  1050.63  1070.92  1048.40  ...  1802400          0             0
GOOG 2019-06-10  1072.98  1092.66  1072.32  ...  1464200          0             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    tkr = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    hist = tkr.history(period="1y")
    df2 = df2.append(hist)
    df2['Ticker'] = ticker

    print(df2.reset_index())  


        Date     Open     High      Low    Close   Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits Ticker
0 2019-06-06  1044.99  1047.49  1033.70  1044.34  1703200          0             0   GOOG
1 2019-06-07  1050.63  1070.92  1048.40  1066.04  1802400          0             0   GOOG
2 2019-06-10  1072.98  1092.66  1072.32  1080.38  1464200          0             0   GOOG
3 2019-06-11  1093.98  1101.99  1077.60  1078.72  1436700          0             0   GOOG
4 2019-06-12  1078.00  1080.93  1067.54  1077.03  1061000          0             0   GOOG
        Date     Open     High      Low    Close   Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits Ticker
0 2019-06-06  1044.99  1047.49  1033.70  1044.34  1703200          0             0   AMZN
1 2019-06-07  1050.63  1070.92  1048.40  1066.04  1802400          0             0   AMZN
2 2019-06-10  1072.98  1092.66  1072.32  1080.38  1464200          0             0   AMZN
3 2019-06-11  1093.98  1101.99  1077.60  1078.72  1436700          0             0   AMZN
4 2019-06-12  1078.00  1080.93  1067.54  1077.03  1061000          0             0   AMZN
```